# tesseract.js sample code not working

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to make Tesseract.js working.

I have taken a very simple code from the web, apprarently declared as working, but it doesn't.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
        <title>Tesseract Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="fileInput">Choose File to OCR:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="document-content">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            fileInput.addEventListener('change', handleInputChange);
        });

        function handleInputChange(event){
            var input = event.target;
            var file = input.files[0];
            console.log(file);
            Tesseract.recognize(file)
                .progress(function(message){
                    console.log(message);
                })
                .then(function(result){
                    var contentArea = document.getElementById('document-content');
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

This is their main website: http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, but I had to make this change:

```
.then(function(result) {
  var contentArea = document.getElementById('document-content');
  contentArea.innerHTML = result.text;
})
```

(The example you posted only logs to the console.)

Comment: for some reasons i has issues logging the console but it's working displaying content in the contentArea. thank you

Comment: also, do you know why it only works on firefox but not on explorer or chrome?

Comment: Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8aL31upr/ Works fine in Chrome 54 and IE 11. Did you check the console?

Comment: Most of the times i get this error: Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': An object could not be cloned.

Comment: When you run it for the first time, the script has to download several large resource files. Just clear your cache and watch the demo on the tesseract page, and you will see several bars showing how various stuff is loaded.

Comment: i even tried with anonymous navigation on google chrome (which does not save cookie / acches) but i have the same "no" result. I know it loads various stuff, but as it works fine on firefox, why doesn't with other browsers? It's working in jsfiddle only

Comment: Wait, are you saying the fiddle works in chrome, but your own code doesn't?

Comment: i'm saying the fiddle works, and if i use the same code as in the fiddle on my own, in local, it does not. (at least for chrome and IE, cuz working fine on firefox)

Comment: What do you mean by "local"? A server running on `localhost`? Or an html file? Because if the latter, that might be the reason.